# Is there an algorithm to find the optimal placement of 1D boxes on a line?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, range

I am trying to find an optimal way to place a set of ranges in a larger range. I like to think of it as flat boxes that can move left or right. Some things to consider:

- There are N boxes, each of them with a center point Ci.
- There are N attractor points (one per box), we can call them Pi. Each box is attracted to one attractor point with a force proportional to the distance.
- The order of the boxes is fixed. The order of the attractor points and of the boxes is the same. So C1 is attracted to P1, C2 to P2, etc.
- The boxes cannot overlap.

I made a diagram that may make it easier to understand:

[image]

The question is, what algorithm can I use to move the boxes around so that each Ci is the closest possible to its respective Pi. In other words, how do I find the locations for the Ci points that minimizes the distance (Li) between all Ci-Pi pairs?

I'd also be helpful if you can point me in to some material to read or something, I'm not very familiar with this type of problems... My guess is that some sort of force-directed algorithm would work but I'm not sure how to implement those.

Comment: Are C's and P's one-to-one?  Or can two or more points be paired with the same C?

Comment: Do you want to minimize the sum of `Li` or the sum of `Li²`? The former is easy while the latter would somewhat model the L segments in your drawings as springs.

Comment: @KotaMori C's and P's are one to one and no, no two points are paired with the same C.

Comment: @Nelfeal I was thinking of minimizing Li rather than the Li^2 but I'd probably be happy with any...

Comment: Sorry but I'm still not sure about the question.. are you trying to minimize the total length from the start of the first box to the end of the last box? like the optimal solution would (if it is possible) would be to take the 2 smallest boxes and put on each end?  could you be more formal mathematically?

Comment: @JackRaBeat I edited the question, hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: @Athe Now that you've edited: minimizing the sum of `Li` and minimizing each `Li` according to some force aren't the same thing. What you want is to find the natural rest state (state of lowest potential energy) of a system where the L segments are springs.

Comment: @Athe Now that you've edited: minimizing the sum of `Li` and minimizing each `Li` according to some force aren't the same thing. What you want is to find the natural rest state (state of lowest potential energy) of a system where the L segments are springs.

Comment: If the force of each Li increases as the length increases, wouldn't the natural rest state be the state that minimizes the length of all Lis?

Comment: No. Take P1=1, P2=3, P3=3, and all three boxes have length 2. If you put C1 and C2 at P1 and P2, and then C3=5, all boxes touch and you have minimized the *sum* L1+L2+L3 (0+0+2 = 2). But if you have forces, the force between P3 and C3 will push the boxes to the left and then you get a different sum where L1 and L2 increase and L3 decreases. That sum is x+x+(2-x) = 2+x, and that's more than the previous sum.

Comment: With the same example, if you care about the sum of all `Li²` instead, you get the first sum being 0²+0²+2² = 4, while the second sum is x²+x²+(2-x)² = 3x²-4x+4, and you can find the minimum at x=2/3, which is 8/3 (2.66...), and that's indeed less than 4.

Comment: You are totally right I think indeed I care more about the squared distances (so the forces) than the sum of the distances. Your response below gave me some idea on how to approximate the problem though, I'll try to implement a solution and see what I get. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: This is a simplified version of graph rendering. A standard solution for that problem is (as some have mentioned) model it as a spring system with collision constraints. Then pick a reasonable starting configuration and solve the system over time with an integrator to find the least energy configuration. That will work here, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "each box is attracted to one attractor point with a force proportional to the distance", you are describing a system where the boxes are attached to the attractor points by springs (see [Hooke's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law)), and you want to determine the state of the system at rest (the state of minimum potential energy).

Because the forces are proportional to the distances, what you want is to minimize the sum of the distances squared, or the sum of `Li^2` from `i=0` to `i=n`. Here is an algorithm to do that.

The idea is to group boxes that need to touch by the end and figure out their position as a group based on their corresponding attractor points.

The first step is not to find these groups, because we can actually start with one big group and cut it later if necessary. For simplicity, let's treat all `Li` as signed distances. So `Li = Ci-Pi`. Let's also name the sizes of the boxes, though it will be easier to handle half-sizes. So let `Si` be half the size of the i-th box. Finally, let's write the sum of `Xi` from `i=a` to `i=b` like `sum[a,b](Xi)`.

Here is how to compute the position of a group of boxes, assuming each one touches the next. `Li` is a function of the position of the group: if `x` is that position, `Li(x) = Ci(x) - Pi` (where `Ci(x)` is just `x` plus some constant). `x` can be point of the group of box, for example the left edge of the first box.
We also know that `sum[a,b](Li(x)^2)` must be minimal. This means the derivative of that sum must be zero: `sum[a,b](2*Li(x)) = 0`. So:

```
sum[a,b](2*Li) = 0
sum[a,b](Li) = 0
sum[a,b](Ci - Pi) = 0
sum[a,b](Ci) = sum[a,b](Pi)
```

Computing `sum[a,b](Pi)` is trivial, and `sum[a,b](Ci)` can be expressed in terms of `Ca` (center of the first box), since `C[i+1] = Ci + Si + S[i+1]`.

Now that you can compute the position of a group of boxes, do it first with a group made of all boxes, and then remove boxes from that group as follows.
Starting from the left, consider all boxes with `Li > 0` and compute `Q = sum(Li)` for all corresponding `i`. Similarly, starting from the right, consider all boxes with `Li < 0` and compute `R = -sum(Li)` for all corresponding `i` (note that negative sign, because we want the absolute value). Now, if `Q > R`, remove the boxes on the left and make a new group with them, otherwise remove the boxes on the right and make a new group with them.
You cannot make these two new groups at the same time, because removing boxes from one end can change the position of the original group, where boxes you would have removed from the other end should not be removed.

If you made a new group, repeat: compute the position of each separate group of boxes (they will never overlap at this point), and remove boxes if necessary. Otherwise, you have your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer, I'll try to implement this (although I found a different solution). Just a suggestion, maybe you could write the algorithm steps more in pseudocode style rather than text, it's a bit difficult to follow.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the objective is a quadratic function and all the constraints are linear. So I think you can solve it by standard quadratic programming solvers.
If we write `S_i` be the half-size of i-th box, and the Pi's are given, then:

```
Minimize y 
with respect to C_1, C_2, ...C_n

subject to

y = sum_i (P_i - C_i)^2
C_i + S_i + S_{i+1} <= C_{i+1}   for each i = 1, ... n-1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: this is a crude solution to minimize the sum of all `Li`, which is no longer the question.**

Let's name the boxes B, so `Bi` has center `Ci`. Let `n` be the number of boxes and points.
Assuming all the boxes can fit into the larger range, here is how I would do it:

Let `Q(a, b)` be the average of `Pi` from `i=a` to `i=b`.
Place all the boxes next to each other (in order) to form a superbox, so that the center of this superbox is at `Q(1, n)`.
If it goes over one end of the larger range, move it so that it sits at the limit.

Then, for each `Bi`, move it as close to `Pi` as possible without moving other boxes (and while still being inside the larger range). Repeat until you can't move any more box.

Now, the only way to minimize the sum of all `Li` is as follows.
Let `G` be a group of boxes that touch. Let `F(G)` be the predicate: if the center boxes of a series are `Bi` and `Bj` (if there are an odd number of boxes in the series, `i=j`), then `Ci != Pi` and `Cj != Pj`.
Find a `G` such that `F(G)` is true, and move the corresponding boxes so that `F(G)` becomes false. If the group of boxes hit another box while moving, add that box to the group and repeat. Of course, don't move any box outside the larger range.

Once there is no `G` for which `F(G)` is true or for which you would need to move outside the larger range, you have your solution (one of potentially an infinite number).

Comment: To your first solution, yes that works but is not very good. The solution will depend on which side you move all your boxes, and the first boxes that move will likely be close to their center point while the last boxes that move will be very far away (because there's no more room).

Comment: For the second solution, I'm not sure I understand it. If I do, it seems to me that there are situations where no movement of any group G can make Ci = Pi and Cj = Pj. Think of two very large boxes in the middle of the set, with attractor points very close to the center of the line. Those boxes will prevent any movement that makes Ci = Pi and Cj = Pj...

Comment: I'm not presenting two different solutions. This is just one algorithm, and it does minimize the sum of all `Li`. Take your example with two very large boxes in the middle and all the points close to the center. If there are as many boxes on either end, then it doesn't matter how you move them as long as they all touch, the sum of all `Li` will stay the same. If there are more boxes on one end, then the center box is on that end, and you need to move everything toward the other end, thus minimizing the sum of all `Li`.

Comment: What you describe amounts to minimizing the sum of all `Li²` instead. I'm not sure if it would work, but you could try the same algorithm but with `F(G)` being "the center of G (the group superbox) isn't at `Q(a, b)` with `Ba` and `Bb` the boxes at either end of G". In other words, move the center of mass of G closer to the center of mass of the corresponding points.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completion, I found a (probably subtompimal) solution that works pretty well and is very easy to implement.

1. Place all boxes with their Ci's at their Pi's.
2. Go over all boxes, from left to right and do the following:

   1. Check if box i overlaps with the box to its left. If it is the first box, check if it overlaps with the range minimum.
   2. If there is overlap, move the box to the right so that there is no left overlap.
3. Repeat step 2 but from right to left, checking right overlaps (or range maximum for the last box).
4. Repeat steps 2-3 until no more overlaps remain or a maximum number of repetitions is reached.

It's quite efficient for my relatively small dataset and I get good results with 10 repetitions of steps 2-3 (5 left to right checks, 5 right to left checks).